# Show Capture images and gallary images in Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-camera

I am trying to show Camera capture images and gallary images in `Recyclerview`. It works fine but when I capture a second image or select from gallary it replaces the first image in `Recyclerview`. I want to show all images in `Recyclerview` that I have selected or captured from camera.

Activity code:

```
public void ShowDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AttachDisputeDocActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rc_img_dialog_layt);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    layoutParams.dimAmount = 0.5f;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
    dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

    RelativeLayout UploadImage = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rela_upload);
    RelativeLayout TakeCamera = dialog.findViewById(R.id.rela_camera);
    UploadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AttachDisputeDocActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AttachDisputeDocActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, DspConstant.REQUEST_GALLARY_IMAGE);
                } else {
                    gallaryintent();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    dialog.show();
    TakeCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AttachDisputeDocActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AttachDisputeDocActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, DspConstant.REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                } else {
                    openCameraIntent();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private void openCameraIntent() {
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    pictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if (pictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".fileprovider", photoFile);
            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, DspConstant.REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    }
}

private void gallaryintent() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    galleryIntent .setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, DspConstant.REQUEST_GALLARY_IMAGE);
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    imagefilepath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DspConstant.REQUEST_GALLARY_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        loadRecyclerView(picturePath);
    } else if (requestCode == DspConstant.REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE && requestCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        loadRecyclerView(imagefilepath);
    }
}

private void loadRecyclerView(String image) {
    documentlist.add(image);
    attachDocAdapter = new AttachDocAdapter(this, documentlist);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(attachDocAdapter);
    attachDocAdapter.updateList(documentlist);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case DspConstant.REQUEST_GALLARY_IMAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                gallaryintent();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
        case DspConstant.REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCameraIntent();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Adapter Code:

```
public class AttachDocAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttachDocAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> imageslist=new ArrayList<>();
private Activity activity;

public AttachDocAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> imageslist)
{
    this.activity=activity;
    this.imageslist=imageslist;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView img_document;
    CitiTextView txt_deleteimage;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img_document=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_document);
        txt_deleteimage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_delete);
    }
}
@Override
public AttachDocAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemview= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rc_img_attach_layout,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemview);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AttachDocAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(activity).load(imageslist.get(position)).into(holder.img_document);
    holder.txt_deleteimage.setOnClickListener(view -> removeItem(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (imageslist==null)
    {
        return 0;
    }return imageslist.size();
}
public void updateList(ArrayList<String> imageslist) {
    this.imageslist = imageslist;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void removeItem(int position) {
    imageslist.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
   }
```

And when I click on TakeCamera nothing happens on the Samsung S5.

Comment: `attachDocAdapter.updateList(documentlist);` this is redundant since you are creating a new adapter everytime a new image is picked.

Comment: Need to see your `onCreate` and `onStart` code of activity.